# How does lowess handle gaps in time series?

Tags: time-series, python, statsmodels, smoothing, loess

I have been using the lowess smoother to calculate trends for time series data for a while now but until now my data was always without gaps.

I now have to work with data where there are quite large gaps in time (~2h for minute sampled data so ~120 missing samples) and by reading the documentation and looking at the actual implementation of the lowess smoother in the statsmodels package I couldn't really find out how it handles missing data.

The produced trend for data is obviously not correct and the console output confirms that this somehow causes a problem since I get warnings regarding dividing by zero or another invalid number.

Any fraction of data over 0.03 results in a trend that reaches 1e26 while the data is closer to 0.4. Lower values produce a trend which does not follow the data as it should with such a low value. Does anyone know how exactly gaps are handled or if I have to divide my data into chunks without gaps?

EDIT: I just found the error, numpy and python integers have different sizes so for my data some timestamps were suddenly negative resulting in the spiky trend.

Comment: From the documentation `missing : Available options are ‘none’, ‘drop’, and ‘raise’. If ‘none’, no nan checking is done. If ‘drop’, any observations with nans are dropped. If ‘raise’, an error is raised. Default is ‘drop’.`

Comment: Yes, I read that too but that flag is only for NaN values in the time series while my series has a gap without values. The measurement stopped and was continued later so also the timestamps in between are missing.

Comment: In that case it's not different than if you had some numeric values in the range 50-100 and 150-200 (example), with a gap between 100-150 of no values, it would just extrapolate some values which may or may not make sense.

Comment: I thought the same, however it seems like the gaps also introduce errors in later parts of the trend where sufficient data is given. Additionally, the calculated trend also has the same amount of values as the original data, so if there was any kind of interpolation it would have been only internally  which makes it way harder to understand what is actually happening.

Comment: That's because lowess uses a certain % of nearby points to estimate a trend, which will be distorted in case of extrapolation. You could try increasing this %, it could help.

Comment: That's exactly what I attempted at first but increasing the percentage, as I mentioned in my question, distorts the trend even further with exploding values. I guess I have to either omit the gaps or use a different method for the trend.

Comment: Watch out: lowess implementations in different software are not guaranteed identical. It's my impression that the original implementation defined bandwidth as a fraction of time or other range, so different estimates may easily be based on different numbers of observations, even if the data are evenly spaced.

Comment: A little note for people who land in this question (probably not the OP's case): missing data in time series can be either "real" missing data or zeroes. I've seen lots of sales and demand forecasts done that considered missing data as real missing data, because no sales had been recorded. Missing data in sales (or demand) often means there were no sales, or that sales were zero. Treating those cases as "missing data" will throw a mathematically-correct erroneous forecast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't do anything with missing data by itself. If there is some default handling of missing data in the implementation of the algorithm you are referring to, this should be described in the documentation.

[LOWESS is a (local) regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression), so it predicts something as a function of something else. If I understand correctly, in your scenario, you are dealing with time-series, so you predict the values $y_t$ using their time index $t$. In such a case, as in any other regression model, it will interpolate the intermediate points. This is exactly what you see in [the example from the R's documentation for `lowess`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lowess): there were no cars with `speed` equal to 21 and the regression line interpolates between what it predicted for the nearby points. In your case, the $x$-axis would be time.

[image: LOWESS example from the R documentation.]

If you are using some kind of errors, they are due to how you are using the software and what exactly is your data. You didn't give us much details on it, so it is hard to comment.

Comment: My data consists of physical measurement values that are sampled each minute with corresponding timestamps. During the measurement, there was a 2h downtime during which no measurement was done resulting in a 2h gap without timestamps or measurement values. Since I am interested in whether a trend continues over the day my plan was to keep the gaps to retain any effects caused by it. Sadly I am not allowed to share plots or the data itself but it seems like the gaps have a lasting effect on later values of the lowess trend even with sufficient data given at that point in time.

Comment: @Krautsultan I can't comment on the results you are seeing without knowing what they are, but the answer still applies: lowess would interpolate for the points that were not seen in the data. If lowess does not work for your data, it may be the case that you simply need to use something else.

Comment: It uses **linear** interpolation